# SQL SELECT FROM TWO TABLES INNER JOIN

Tags: sql, select, insert

I am trying select from my `Album` and `ArtistBand` Table and display the `Name` and `Bandname` in alphabetical order. When in try to use the select statement below it shows up with all the albums on each band. Any help would be appreciated project for school.

```
CREATE TABLE ArtistBand 
(
    ArtistID INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    BandName VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    NameOfMembers VARCHAR(255),
    NumberOfMembers INT
);

CREATE TABLE Genre
(
    GenreID INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    GenreType VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE Album 
(
    AlbumID INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    Name VARCHAR (255) NOT NULL,
    ReleaseDate DATE NOT NULL,
    Producers VARCHAR (255),
    ArtistID INT,
    GenreID INT,
    FOREIGN KEY(ArtistID) REFERENCES ArtistBand(ArtistID),
    FOREIGN KEY (GenreID) REFERENCES Genre (GenreID)
);

CREATE TABLE LookUp
(
    AlbumID INT,
    GenreID INT,
    FOREIGN KEY (AlbumID) REFERENCES Album (AlbumID),
    FOREIGN KEY (GenreID) REFERENCES Genre (GenreID)
);

INSERT INTO ArtistBand 
VALUES
    (NULL,'ACDC','BrianJohnson',4),
    (NULL,'Metallica','JamesHeitfield',4),
    (NULL,'TheBeatles','JohnLennon',4),
    (NULL,'JayZ','ShawnCarter',1),
    (NULL,'DangerMouse','BrianBurton',1);

INSERT INTO Album 
VALUES
    (NULL,'BackInBlack','1980-01-01',NULL,NULL,NULL),
    (NULL,'TheBlackAlbum','1991-01-01',NULL,NULL,NULL),
    (NULL,'WhiteAlbum','1968-01-01',NULL,NULL,NULL),
    (NULL,'TheBlackAlbum','2003-01-01',NULL,NULL,NULL),
    (NULL,'TheGreyAlbum','2004-01-01',NULL,NULL,NULL);

INSERT INTO Genre 
VALUES
    (NULL,'HeavyMetal'),
    (NULL,'HeavyMetal'),
    (NULL,'Pop'),
    (NULL,'HipHop'),
    (NULL,'HipHop');

SELECT   
    ArtistBand.BandName, Album.Name
FROM     
    ArtistBand
JOIN     
    Album 
ORDER BY 
    ArtistBand.BandName;
```

Comment: As told by rcs below you should 'always' join based on a condition. Failing to do so will fetch Cartesian products. So if your table_1 has 100 records, table_2 has another 100, then you will end up with 100*100=10k records.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add condition on your join, that the `ArtistID` should be the same in both tables. So your query will look like below:

```
SELECT   ArtistBand.BandName, Album.Name
FROM     ArtistBand
JOIN     Album ON ArtistBand.ArtistID = Album.ArtistID
ORDER BY ArtistBand.BandName;
```